# top - Show graphical load on startup (interactive commands 1, t, m)

Tags: top

I'd like to see the current load (cpu + mem) of my Server (rhel 7.x) in a graphical fashion and only have `top` (and other built-in commands) available, tools like `htop` (that need to be installed) are not available.

Currently I start `top` and then type <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd> and <kbd>m</kbd> to archive and output like this one:

[image: top graphical output with bars]

Is there a way to start `top` with this view or send keystrokes to it automatically after start?
The man page only mentions the parameter `-1` which kind of replaces the keystroke <kbd>1</kbd>, but it doesn't accept -t or -m as parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the current `top` "dashboard" by simply pressing `shift+w` (uppercase `W`). From [top man page:](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)

```
W  :Write-the-Configuration-File
              This will save all of your options and toggles plus the
              current display mode and delay time.  By issuing this
              command just before quitting top, you will be able restart
              later in exactly that same state.
```